# Why did my @-mention not get triggered? Was it because I put a period after the username?

Tags: bug

On [How can I transform an image for Apple Watch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33090032/how-can-i-transform-an-image-for-apple-watch?noredirect=1#comment53997138_33090032), I received a helpful comment from one user, GeneratorOfOne, and wrote a link request that began: `Thank you, @GeneratorOfOne.`

On the page as rendered, the `@GeneratorOfOne` is rendered literally, with an '@' and without a link.

Looks like a bug to me...

Comment: .... because you're not on twitter?

Comment: Haha, yeah, the OP had me second guessing myself. No mentions are ever highlighted or linked on SO. It just notifies the mentioned user.

Comment: Because that's not how this works. If I say @TZHX, it will not become a link. By design.

Comment: Dupe on uber-meta: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Answer (score 9):

Because that's not how this works.
If I say `@TZHX` in comments, it will not become a link. It will only notify [@TZHX](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/519348/tzhx)

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).